# IPSEC/IKEv2 StrongSwan applies only the first route from split-include, the rest is ignored

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, ipsec

I have an IPSEC/IKEv2 VPN server (on a MikroTik router) and I'm trying to connect to it from my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS system. The server uses x509 certificates and private/public key pairs for authentication. I can connect to the server, but not all routes pushed by the server are  applied on the client side.

**This is the question: why doesn't it apply all routes? How can I fix this?**

Details below.

The remote side (VPN server) has:

- Private (office) LAN: 192.168.13.0/24
- Pool reserved for VPN clients: 10.0.88.0/24
- FQDN *.my.server.hu (replaced the real name)
- Public WAN address 1.2.3.5  (replaced the real IP)
- It also has other internal networks connected (this is why I need to push multiple routes from the VPN server)

The local (VPN client) side has:

- Private (home) LAN: 192.168.14.0/24
- VPN client IP (offered by the VPN server): 10.0.88.100
- Public WAN address 1.2.3.4  (replaced the real IP)

After I connect to the VPN server, I see this in the routing table:

```
root@laci-ryzen:~# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.14.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 enp5s0
1.2.3.4         192.168.14.1    255.255.255.255 UGH       0 0          0 enp5s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 enp5s0
192.168.14.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp5s0
192.168.14.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 enp5s0
root@laci-ryzen:~#
```

As you can see, there is

- the default gateway 192.168.14.1
- a route to the public WAN address (replaced with 1.2.3.4)
- a link-local default address 169.254.0.0
- a route to the private (home) LAN 192.168.14.0/24
- a direct route to the local (home) router 192.168.14.1.

There are no routes to 10.0.88.0/24 nor 192.168.13.0/24.

The first route given in split-include is added as an ip transformation.

```
root@laci-ryzen:~# ip xfrm state
src 192.168.14.2 dst 1.2.3.5
    proto esp spi 0x0c51282e reqid 4 mode tunnel
    replay-window 0 flag af-unspec
    auth-trunc hmac(sha512) 0xfa80fddcd4db0019e7e8f2cc1b3ad3487cff50f27267376b2dc189d790488abb1aa08f6473146e7cde697c696dbbf64f62e1e6e928b72cbb8d8fd7b22b164a58 256
    enc cbc(aes) 0x09d94b3501a7e95ec20c7378c6493d591f291b8819a4a9c69de25f1a8918afb3
    encap type espinudp sport 54067 dport 4500 addr 0.0.0.0
    anti-replay context: seq 0x0, oseq 0xb, bitmap 0x00000000
src 1.2.3.5 dst 192.168.14.2
    proto esp spi 0xcf16ebb2 reqid 4 mode tunnel
    replay-window 32 flag af-unspec
    auth-trunc hmac(sha512) 0xc38ba5586eb6c06d34b92a606ca3a1e6aec988adad87c3f6def719ba3c9a371aafabfd52f240e320d23c39a0bcd06f718a69830d2098757ca6121cee3d50deaf 256
    enc cbc(aes) 0x89807b8796ecfd5975f143dae279af70aa7e52ab9b4d123fa84901743d90db10
    encap type espinudp sport 4500 dport 54067 addr 0.0.0.0
    anti-replay context: seq 0x7, oseq 0x0, bitmap 0x0000007f


root@laci-ryzen:~# ip xfrm policy  | head -20
src 192.168.14.1/32 dst 192.168.14.1/32 
    dir fwd priority 167231 
src 192.168.14.1/32 dst 192.168.14.1/32 
    dir in priority 167231 
src 192.168.14.1/32 dst 192.168.14.1/32 
    dir out priority 167231 
src 10.0.88.100/32 dst 192.168.13.0/24 
    dir out priority 371327 
    tmpl src 192.168.14.2 dst 1.2.3.5
        proto esp spi 0x0c51282e reqid 4 mode tunnel
src 192.168.13.0/24 dst 10.0.88.100/32 
    dir fwd priority 371327 
    tmpl src 1.2.3.5 dst 192.168.14.2
        proto esp reqid 4 mode tunnel
src 192.168.13.0/24 dst 10.0.88.100/32 
    dir in priority 371327 
    tmpl src 1.2.3.5 dst 192.168.14.2
        proto esp reqid 4 mode tunnel
src fe80::/64 dst fe80::/64 
    dir fwd priority 134463
```

It seems that packets for 192.168.13.0/24 are transformed and routed to the VPN server correctly. But packets for 10.0.88.0/100 are not.

These routes should be added automatically, because they are present in split-include, on the VPN server:

```
/ip ipsec mode-config
add address-pool=vpn.my.server.hu address-prefix-length=32 name="modeconf vpn.my.server.hu" split-include=192.168.13.0/24,10.0.88.0/24 static-dns=10.0.88.1 system-dns=no
```

The problem is not with the VPN server, because the routes are applied correctly when I connect to it from Windows 10. On Windows 10, routes for 192.168.13.0/24 and 10.0.88.0/24 are added and I can ping the remote address 10.0.88.1 and also 192.168.13.254 (They are the VPN server's addresses on different networks).

**UPDATE**

Whatever routes I give in split-include on the server, the first one is applied correctly by strongswan on the client side. But the rest is not.

So for example, if I change the server config to this:

```
/ip ipsec mode-config
add address-pool=vpn.my.server.hu address-prefix-length=32 name="modeconf vpn.my.server.hu" split-include=172.111.0.0/16,192.168.13.0/24,10.0.88.0/24 static-dns=10.0.88.1 system-dns=no
```

Then 172.111.0.0/16 is correctly added by strongswan, but 192.168.13.0/24 and 10.0.88.0/24 are not.

I really need to add multiple routes, one is not enough.

Here is my syslog (IP addresses and host names replaced):

```
Dec 22 14:10:55 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642655.8085] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13" name="laci@my.server.hu" pid=2578 uid=1001 result="success"
Dec 22 14:10:55 laci-ryzen gnome-shell[1662]: JS ERROR: TypeError: item is undefined#012setActiveConnections/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1523:17#012setActiveConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1520:24#012_syncVpnConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1867:26
Dec 22 14:10:55 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642655.8095] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Dec 22 14:10:55 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642655.8265] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Dec 22 14:10:55 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 05[CFG] received initiate for NetworkManager connection laci@my.server.hu
Dec 22 14:10:55 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 05[CFG] using CA certificate, gateway identity 'vpn.my.server.hu'
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 05[IKE] initiating IKE_SA laci@my.server.hu[2] to 1.2.3.5
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 05[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 05[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.14.2[37786] to 1.2.3.5[500] (1128 bytes)
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642657.4221] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 08[NET] received packet: from 1.2.3.5[500] to 192.168.14.2[37786] (38 bytes)
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 08[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ N(INVAL_KE) ]
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 08[IKE] peer didn't accept DH group ECP_256, it requested MODP_2048
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 08[IKE] initiating IKE_SA laci@my.server.hu[2] to 1.2.3.5
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 08[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(HASH_ALG) N(REDIR_SUP) ]
Dec 22 14:10:57 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 08[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.14.2[37786] to 1.2.3.5[500] (1320 bytes)
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[NET] received packet: from 1.2.3.5[500] to 192.168.14.2[37786] (429 bytes)
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) CERTREQ ]
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[CFG] selected proposal: IKE:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[IKE] local host is behind NAT, sending keep alives
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[IKE] sending cert request for "C=HU, ST=Heves, L=Eger, O=my.server.hu, CN=my.server.hu"
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[IKE] authentication of 'C=HU, ST=Heves, L=Eger, O=my.server.hu, CN=laci@vpn.my.server.hu' (myself) with RSA signature successful
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[IKE] sending end entity cert "C=HU, ST=Heves, L=Eger, O=my.server.hu, CN=laci@vpn.my.server.hu"
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[IKE] establishing CHILD_SA laci@my.server.hu{2}
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi CERT N(INIT_CONTACT) CERTREQ AUTH CPRQ(ADDR ADDR6 DNS NBNS DNS6) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(ADD_4_ADDR) N(EAP_ONLY) N(MSG_ID_SYN_SUP) ]
Dec 22 14:10:58 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[NET] sending packet: from 192.168.14.2[44719] to 1.2.3.5[4500] (2560 bytes)
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[NET] received packet: from 1.2.3.5[4500] to 192.168.14.2[44719] (2304 bytes)
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH response 1 [ CERT IDr AUTH CPRP(ADDR MASK SUBNET SUBNET DNS) TSi TSr SA N(ADD_TS_POSS) ]
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[IKE] received end entity cert "C=HU, ST=Heves, L=Eger, O=my.server.hu, CN=vpn.my.server.hu"
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG]   using certificate "C=HU, ST=Heves, L=Eger, O=my.server.hu, CN=vpn.my.server.hu"
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG]   using trusted ca certificate "C=HU, ST=Heves, L=Eger, O=my.server.hu, CN=my.server.hu"
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG] checking certificate status of "C=HU, ST=Heves, L=Eger, O=my.server.hu, CN=vpn.my.server.hu"
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG] certificate status is not available
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG]   reached self-signed root ca with a path length of 0
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[IKE] authentication of 'vpn.my.server.hu' with RSA signature successful
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[IKE] IKE_SA laci@my.server.hu[2] established between 192.168.14.2[C=HU, ST=Heves, L=Eger, O=my.server.hu, CN=laci@vpn.my.server.hu]...1.2.3.5[vpn.my.server.hu]
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[IKE] scheduling rekeying in 35488s
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[IKE] maximum IKE_SA lifetime 36088s
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG] handling INTERNAL_IP4_NETMASK attribute failed
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG] handling INTERNAL_IP4_SUBNET attribute failed
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG] handling INTERNAL_IP4_SUBNET attribute failed
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[IKE] installing new virtual IP 10.0.88.100
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen avahi-daemon[1177]: Registering new address record for 10.0.88.100 on enp5s0.IPv4.
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon: 05[KNL] 10.0.88.100 appeared on enp5s0
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_512_256/NO_EXT_SEQ
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1946] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) reply received.
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 06[IKE] CHILD_SA laci@my.server.hu{2} established with SPIs c7ea1582_i 0d47fc2e_o and TS 10.0.88.100/32 === 192.168.13.0/24
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1947] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1948] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data: VPN Gateway: 1.2.3.5
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data: Tunnel Device: (null)
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data: IPv4 configuration:
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data:   Internal Address: 10.0.88.100
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data:   Internal Prefix: 32
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data:   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 10.0.88.100
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data:   Internal DNS: 10.0.88.1
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data:   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1950] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: Data: No IPv6 configuration
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1608642659.1954] vpn-connection[0x5616750ee2e0,e430f863-b8b7-4f23-8b49-0fd2a8036d13,"laci@my.server.hu",0]: VPN connection: (IP Config Get) complete
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen dbus-daemon[1185]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=1186 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen dbus-daemon[1185]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen dunst[3085]: WARNING: No icon found in path: 'gnome-lockscreen'
Dec 22 14:10:59 laci-ryzen charon-nm: 09[IKE] installed bypass policy for 192.168.14.1/32
```

I think the interesting part is this:

```
VPN plugin: state changed: started (4)
VPN connection: (IP4 Config Get) reply received
Data: VPN Gateway: 1.2.3.5
Data: Tunnel Device: (null)
Data: IPv4 configuration:
Data:   Internal Address: 10.0.88.100
Data:   Internal Prefix: 32
Data:   Internal Point-to-Point Address: 10.0.88.100
Data:   Internal DNS: 10.0.88.1
Data:   DNS Domain: '(none)'
Data: No IPv6 configuration
VPN connection: (IP Config Get) complete
```

This is how I setup my strongswan client:

[image]

For completeness, here are some fragments from my VPN server config (routeros):

```
/ip ipsec mode-config
add address-pool=vpn.my.server.hu address-prefix-length=32 name="modeconf vpn.my.server.hu" split-include=192.168.13.0/24,10.0.88.0/24 static-dns=10.0.88.1 system-dns=no
/ip ipsec policy group
add name="group vpn.my.server.hu"
/ip ipsec profile
add dh-group=modp2048,modp1536,modp1024 enc-algorithm=aes-256,aes-192,aes-128 hash-algorithm=sha256 name="profile vpn.my.server.hu"
/ip ipsec peer
add exchange-mode=ike2 local-address=1.2.3.5 name="peer 1.2.3.5" passive=yes profile="profile vpn.my.server.hu"
/ip ipsec proposal
set [ find default=yes ] auth-algorithms=sha512,sha256,sha1 enc-algorithms=aes-256-cbc,aes-128-cbc pfs-group=modp2048
add auth-algorithms=sha512,sha256,sha1 enc-algorithms=aes-256-cbc,aes-256-ctr,aes-256-gcm,aes-192-ctr,aes-192-gcm,aes-128-cbc,aes-128-ctr,aes-128-gcm lifetime=8h name="proposal vpn.my.server.hu" pfs-group=\
    modp2048
/ip ipsec identity
add auth-method=digital-signature certificate=vpn.my.server.hu generate-policy=port-strict match-by=certificate mode-config="modeconf vpn.my.server.hu" peer="peer 1.2.3.5" policy-template-group=\
    "group vpn.my.server.hu" remote-certificate=laci@vpn.my.server.hu remote-id=user-fqdn:laci.vpn.my.server.hu
/ip ipsec policy
set 0 dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 src-address=0.0.0.0/0
add dst-address=10.0.88.0/24 group="group vpn.my.server.hu" proposal="proposal vpn.my.server.hu" src-address=0.0.0.0/0 template=yes
```

For comparison, this is what I see in the routing table in Windows 10, using the very same VPN server with the same credentials.

[image]

Comment: Also tried to connect from RouterOS client, and that works too. It adds these networks into ipsec policies. Only StrongSwan is not doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly same problem - MikroTik as VPN server - Windows 10 is accepting provided subnets (after disabling default gateway on remote network), another MikroTik as client is accepting provided subnets. But strongswan accept only first subnet defined in split-tunneling subnets list configured on VPN server. Same behavior on Linux, FreeBSD and Android.

On Android, there is an option to manualy add split-tunneling subnets. On Linux and FreeBSD the only way to solve this problem is to configure one connection per subnet (or "children" in new swanctl configuration syntax).

Comment: Update on my situation: I upgraded to RouterOs version 7, and migrated all VPN connections to wireguard. It cannot push routes, but generating wireguard tunnel configuration files is super easy, and it works reliably. This might not be a solution for you, but it might worth trying.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1232877)